# Solving SDEs in R with Diffeqr package: possible to set seed?

Tags: r, julia, ode, stochastic

Is it possible to set a seed (like `R`'s `set.seed()` function) in the `diffeqr` package in R, while solving stochastic differential equations?

**[Example](https://github.com/cran/diffeqr)**

```
library(diffeqr)
f <- function(u,p,t) {
  return(1.01*u)
}
g <- function(u,p,t) {
  return(0.87*u)
}
u0 = 1/2
tspan <- list(0.0,1.0)
sol = sde.solve(f,g,u0,tspan, alg = "SKenCarp()")
udf = as.data.frame(sol$u)
plotly::plot_ly(udf, x = sol$t, y = sol$u, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
```

I found in the [documentation](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/solvers/sde_solve.html#Full-List-of-Methods-1), that the possibility was present to set a seed, however, if I add it to:

```
sde.solve(f,g,u0,tspan, alg = "SKenCarp()", seed = 123)
```

It won't work. Is it possible to set a seed in this R package?

Comment: It wasn't part of it before, but https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/diffeqr/pull/15 adds that feature. If anyone wants to test it we can get it released!

Comment: That should be it, but then you need to go to the PR branch.

Comment: I managed to install it:)! However, somewhere in the `sde.solve()` function it crashes.. I first thought that it might have something to do with the algorithm (SkenCarp), however, also `alg = 'nothing'` (default) crashed with the tutorial example from above. Are there other things I could try?

Comment: What is it saying for when it crashes for you?

Comment: I see. Fixed it and submitted an update to CRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(diffeqr)
diffeqr::diffeq_setup()
f <- function(u,p,t) {
  return(1.01*u)
}
g <- function(u,p,t) {
  return(0.87*u)
}
u0 = 1/2
tspan <- list(0.0,1.0)
sol = sde.solve(f,g,u0,tspan, alg = "SKenCarp()", seed=1)
udf = as.data.frame(sol$u)
plotly::plot_ly(udf, x = sol$t, y = sol$u, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
```

Now works on diffeqr v0.1.3, which was just submitted to CRAN.

BTW, `SKenCarp` probably isn't the right method for this problem, but I assume you're testing it for other reasons.